Effect of objective function's Hessian's condition number on learning rate in Gradient Descent
I'm following Ian Goodfellow et al. book titled Deep Learning, and in Chapter 4 - Numerical Computation, page 87, he mentions that by utilising second order Taylor approximation of the objective function, we can find the best learning rate $\epsilon^*$:
$$\text{For gradient descent described as: }\mathbf{x}^{(n+1)} = \mathbf{x}^{(n)} - \epsilon \mathbf{g}^{(n)}$$
$$\text{where, } \mathbf{g}^{(n)} =\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^{(n)})$$
$$\text{Using Hessian }\mathbf{H}^{(n)}  = \left[\frac{\partial^2 f (\mathbf{x}^{(n)})}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right]_{ij}$$
$$\text{Best learning rate is }\epsilon^{*(n)} = \frac{\mathbf{g}^{(n)\top} \mathbf{g}^{(n)}}{\mathbf{g}^{(n)\top} \mathbf{H}^{(n)} \mathbf{g}^{(n)}}$$
Now from this I deduced that if $\mathbf{g}^{(n)}$ happens to be an eigenvector of $\mathbf{H}^{(n)}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then:
$$\text{Best learning rate is }\epsilon^{*(n)} = \frac{1}{\lambda}$$
Thus in a way, the magnitude of learning rate in one of its particular eigenvector's direction is larger if its eigenvalue is smaller in magnitude (also noting that the eigenvalue represent the second derivative in that direction).
So, my expectation was that the learning jump would be larger when second derivative of the direction $\mathbf{g}^{(n)}$ largely tends to is small and smaller when $\mathbf{g}^{(n)}$ tends to the eigen-direction with larger second derivative.
To paraphrase: learning jumps are smaller along the steeper slopes than the other way around, thus making this not the best method.
To test this I tried with the function:
$$f([x\; y]^{\top}) = x^2 + 0.01y^2$$
$$\text{with a location independent Hessian } \mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&0.02\end{bmatrix}$$
and arrived with this gradient descent diagram:

Clearly, here the above observation is in agreement that learning rate is small along the steeper slope direction, however the diagram given in the textbook (that uses a similar objective function, just with differently oriented) seems to tell otherwise:

Which seems to do the opposite: the learning jumps seem to be larger along the steeper slope (larger second derivatives) directions even the captions seem to explain with this observation.
While I initially tried to refactor my code for building up my own diagram, I realised that my diagram seems to agree with the mathematics of it.
So I wanted to ask if I am missing on some fact, and that textbook descent is the correct one.
Thanks.
Appendix:
Code for Gradient Descent with Hessian adjusted learning rate:
# Define the function z = f(x, y)
def f(x, y):
    """
    The objective function
    """
    return (1*x**2 + 0.01*y**2)

def g(x, y):
    """
    Objective function's Gradient
    """
    return np.array([2*x, 0.02*y])

def H(x, y):
    """
    Objective function's Hessian
    """
    return np.array([[2, 0], [0, 0.02]])

def learningRate(x, y):
    """
    Learning rate epsilon in gradient descent
    based on considering best second order
    Taylor approximation
    """
    g_ = g(x, y)
    # print(type(g_), g_, sep='\n')
    H_ = H(x, y)

    gTg = np.dot(g_, g_)
    # print(type(gTg), gTg, sep='\n')
    Hg = H_@g_
    gTHg= np.dot(g_, Hg)
    return  gTg / gTHg

def gradientDescent(initialPoint, gradient, learningRate, steps = 5):
    path = [initialPoint]
    for i in range(1, steps+1):
        x0 = np.array(path[i-1])
        newPoint = tuple(x0 - learningRate(*x0)*gradient(*x0))
        path.append(newPoint)
    
    return path


Now that I see this again along with searching for articles related to it, I realise a mistake I did here: I did not notice the scale of X and Y directions - the X direction has like 2 units per scale and Y direction has like 25 units per scale, thus really it turns out the textbook is indeed correct and in my diagram as well, the learning step goes roughly like 10 - 15 units along the steeper slope direction (Y -dir.) while only 2-3 units along the other direction (X - dir.), thus the textbook observation is indeed correct

you can and should make that an answer.
